# Python 3 - Tuple out of range error. But I'm using a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I got a Tuple out of range on my battleships program. The reason I got confused is I'm not using a tuple, unless I'm wrong and I'm willing to be corrected. Tuples are not mutable and the dictionary this is referring to has items added to it upon starting the program. 
I am a beginner so if I have made a stupid mistake please don't judge!

```
from random import randint
#empty list to generate the board.
board = []
messages = {
  "win" : "Nooo you won!",
  "lose" : "Not my ship haha",
  "out" : "Oops, that's not even in the ocean.",
  "repeat" : "You guessed that one already"

}

ships = {
  'shiprows' : [0]
  'shipcols' : [0]
}

#generate board and append to board[] As of now it is a 10*10 grid.
for x in range(0, 10):
  board.append(["O"] * 10)

#prints the board every turn.
def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print(" ".join(row))

print_board(board)

#computer chooses where to put battleships' rows
def random_row1(board):
  return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col1(board):
 return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
#calling above two functions and storing their values for 5 ships.
#creating variables for 5 ships.
vars = 0
for vars in range(0, 5):
  print(vars)
  if len(ships.keys()) >= 4:
    while ships["shiprow{}".format(vars - 2)] == ships["shiprow{}".format(vars - 1)] and ships["shipcol{}".format(vars - 2)] == ships["shipcol{}".format(vars - 1)]:
      ships["shiprow{}".format(vars)] = random_row1(board)
      ships["shipcol{}".format(vars)] = random_col1(board)
    ships["shiprow{}".format(vars)] = random_row1(board)
    ships["shipcol{}".format(vars)] = random_col1(board)
  else:
    ships["shiprow{}".format(vars)] = random_row1(board)
    ships["shipcol{}".format(vars)] = random_col1(board)


#program itself
turn = 0
#enforces four turns before game over. Will possibly extend to unlimited with multiple ships.
print(ships)
for turn in range(20):
  turn = turn + 1
  print ("Turn {}".format(turn))
  print ("Ships Left: {}".format(int(len(ships.keys()) / 2))) 
  guess_row = int(input("Guess Row: "))
  guess_col = int(input("Guess Col: "))

#checking stuff.
  i = 0
  if guess_row == ships["shiprow{}".format(i = range(0, 10))] and guess_col == ships["shipcol{}".format(i)]:
    print (messages["win"])
    board[guess_col][guess_row] = u"#"
    print_board(board)

  elif board[guess_col][guess_row] == "X":
    print ("You guessed that one already.")
  elif guess_row not in range(len(board)) and guess_col not in range(len(board[0])):
    print(messages["out"])
  else:
    print(messages["lose"])
    board[guess_col][guess_row] = "X"
    print_board(board)
  if turn >= 20:
    print ("Game Over")
    board[ships["ship_col{}".format(range(0, 10))]][ships["ship_row{}".format(range(0, 10))]] = u"#"
    print_board(board)
    break
```

Suspect line appears to be line 62 - this one seems sketchy but I don't actually know how to do it. Please advise on what to do:
BTW here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "battleship3.py", line 62, in <module>
    if guess_row == ships["shiprow{}".format(i = range(0, 10))] and guess_col == ships["shipcol{}".format(i)]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thanks.

Comment: What were you expecting `"shiprow{}".format(i=range(0,10))` to do?

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is because you don't use `i` - try `"shiprow{i}".format(...)` instead.  However, this will only fix the error itself.  It seems like you want to use the `format` method for a vectorized lookup of your dictionary - but if you look at the string that gets created here, you'll see that this approach won't work: you'll get `'shiprowrange(0, 10)'`.  (I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't have time at the moment to actually show you how to get what you want - but this is at least why you have the error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error message whenever you use a format string with positional formats specs (like `{}` or `{1}`), but pass only keyword arguments.

Similarly, you get a `KeyError` when you use a format string with only keyword format specs (like `{v}`), but pass only positional arguments:

```
>>> '{}'.format(i=1)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> '{i}'.format(1)
KeyError: 'i'
```

The fix is just to make your specs match your arguments. Either way you like is fine, they just have to be consistent:

```
>>> '{i}'.format(i=1)
1
>>> '{}'.format(1)
1
```

---

All that being said, I'm not sure what the point of this is:

```
"shiprow{}".format(i = range(0, 10))
```

You can fix it either way, but is this really a string you want?

```
>>> "shiprow{i}".format(i = range(0, 10))
'shiprowrange(0, 10)'
>>> "shiprow{}".format(range(0, 10))
'shiprowrange(0, 10)'
```

---

If you're curious *why* you get this error, oversimplifying `format` a bit, it works like this:

```
def format(self, *args, **kwargs):
    result = ''
    index = 0
    bits = self.parse_format_stuff()
    for bit in bits:
        if bit is a regular string:
            result += bit
        elif bit is empty braces:
            result = args[index]
            index += 1
        elif bit is a number in braces:
            result += args[number]
        elif bit is a valid identifier string in braces:
            result += kwargs[identifier]
        else:
            raise a ValueError
    return result
```

So, when it sees that `{}` format spec, it looks for `args[0]`. Since you didn't pass any positional arguments, `args` is the empty tuple `()`, so `args[0]` is an `IndexError`.

Arguably it might be better if `format` handled those errors and turned them into something nicer—but occasionally it's useful to be able to handle the `KeyError` programmatically. (Not so often the `IndexError`, but obviously the two have to work the same way.)

Comment: Hi. The reason I am trying to do this is I have my variables for ship positions as shiprow0, shiprow1, shiprow2 etc... so I am trying to substitute in the variable names as I don't want ten if statements, and potentially more as I improve it.

Comment: To put it simply I want to try and check the user's input against the ship values stored in the dictionary. shiprow0 and shipcol0 pinpoint a location of one ship, so I want to look for if there is a match or not.

Comment: @thatubuntuguy Ir sounds like you want a loop over that range, then, not just a single string packing all 10 of them into one. But, meanwhile, why even have keys named `shiprow0`, `shiprow1`, etc. instead of having one key named `shiprows` whose value is a list of 10 rows, or one key names `ships` whose value is a list of 10 dicts with `row` and `col`, or similar?Then you wouldn’t need any of this complicated formatting keys stuff in the first place.

Comment: That seems like a better idea. Why didn't I think of that before? I'll try that and get back to this.

Comment: I'm getting list out of index when I do this.

Comment: @thatubuntuguy If you've rewritten your code and are getting a new error with your new code, you need to create a new queston.

Answer (score 0):

Getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "shiptest.py", line 51, in <module>
ships['shiprows'][vars] += random_row1(board)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

From changing everything after var=0 to:

```
vars = 0
for vars in range(0, 5):
  print(vars)
  ships['shiprows'][vars] = random_row1(board)
  ships['shipcols'][vars] = random_col1(board)
  print(ships)
```

I think I am making the list in the dictionary wrong. 
Should I use .append()?
EDIT: I used .append() I was an idiot. It is working now thanks for your help!